# KMS.AccessDeniedException when receive SNS message to SQS. KMS key in a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here's the full scenario. My use case requires SNS & SQS with SSE enabled. We are using BYOK KMS keys stored in a central security managed KMS account. Both the SNS Topic and SQS are accessing the key from the same application account. The policy has the following to allow access (note: this isn't the full policy, just the relevant cross account and SNS/SQS stuff):

```
{
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/XYZ",
                    "arn:aws:iam::778899110022:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Amazon SNS to use this key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "sns.amazonaws.com",
                    "sqs.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

No matter what I try, I get the following error from SQS trying to read the message:

"{\"ErrorCode\":\"KMS.AccessDeniedException\",\"ErrorMessage\":\"null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: blahblahblah)\",\"sqsRequestId\":\"Unrecoverable\"}"

All this said... when I create my own key within the KMS account and use that key, I am successful. Unfortunately, our security policy requires the use of their KMS keys. Would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Add following policy to KMS:

```
 {
        "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "kms:CallerAccount": "222222222222",
                "kms:ViaService": "sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    }
```